# How do I dynamically create + insert (append??) a div into a div container?

Tags: javascript

I would like it to end up as this:

```
<div id = "container">

<div id = "dynamicallyCreated"></div>

</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that this involves either document.createElement or appendChild, but I am not quite sure how to use these to insert the newly created div into the container div.

Edit: sorry, I'm not quite sure how to do the code snippet correctly

Answer (score 2):

> I'm pretty sure that this involves either document.createElement or appendChild

Both, actually: :-)

```
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "dynamicallyCreated";
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
```

More to explore [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model): [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

You can also use markup if you prefer via [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
document.getElementById("container").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<div id='dynamicallyCreated'></div>"
);
```

It can add text in front of, after, at the beginning of, or at the end of an element. (Or if adding text, [`insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText).)

If adding not at the end of the container, you can use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Comment: Thank you! So am I correct in assuming that append is for _moving_ elements to places inside the code?

Comment: (Thanks @KristjanKica! There was another one, too. :-) Sorry for the overlapping edit.)

Comment: @newToJS - An element (or more generally, a node) can only be in one place in a document. So if it's already in the document and you use `appendChild` or `insertBefore` or similar to put it somewhere else, it will be removed from its previous location. You can create copies of nodes via `cloneNode` when you want to have a copy instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it :

1. Create element using `document.createElement()`
2. Add attributes (if you wish)
3. Append it to the parent element, using `appendChild()`.

```js
var newEl = document.createElement('div');
newEl.setAttribute("id", "newElement");

document.querySelector("#container").appendChild(newEl);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#newElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Another approach for the same can be done using `innerHTML` property :

```js
document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = "<div id='newElement'></div>"
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#newElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```